# How to give AspectRatio as much space as possible

Tags: user-interface, dart, flutter, aspect-ratio

I have a widget with AspectRatio widget inside and when I put it into Expanded it gets incorrect size (this size doesn't satisfy given AspectRatio).
Is there any way to do get as much space for AspectRatio as possible and stay with given aspectRatio?

I do this way and get 100 units yellow and all another place grey. Instead of grey rectangle with ration width:height equals 2.0.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 100.0,
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 2.0,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wrap your `AspectRatio` widget inside an `Align` or `Center` widget.

```
        Expanded(
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio: 2.0,
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
```